# If R is a symmetric binary relation, what are x and y in set A?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

everyone:

I've been reading my textbook for discrete math and a few other textbooks on the topic of binary relations, and finding that I'm struggling to understand the definitions. I think a lot can be clarified for me if someone can answer one thing:

If R is a symmetric binary relation on Set A, what are x and y in A? For me, it's easy to understand what x and y would be if x and y were in R since the elements of a binary relation are ordered pairs (x,y). Can someone help me visualize what they mean when they say x and y are from A?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Would it be clearer if you said $R$ represents a subset of $A\times A$?

Comment: "what are x and y in A?" they are *elements* of the set$A$.

Comment: Consider a simple example: the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and the binary relation (between numbers): $<$ (less than). In set-theoretic language we have that $<$  is a relation (call it: $\text R$) defined on $\mathbb N$ (i.e. $\text R \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$) that means that it is a set of *pairs* $(n,m)$ such that : $(n,m) \in \text R \text { iff } (n < m)$.

Comment: Please note that $<$ ("our $\text R$") is **not** symmetric, because if $n < m$, then not $(m < n)$. A very simple example of a symmetric relation on $\mathbb N$ is equality: $=$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is some confusion here.

A binary relation (being symmetric or not is not important here) $R$ on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$. Usually, instead of writing $(x,y)\in R$ (and here $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$), we write $x\mathrel Ry$. Anyway, we only write $x\mathrel Ry$ (or $x\mathrel{\not R}y$ when $(x,y)\notin R$) when $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ represents a subset of $A\times A$

You asked for a visualisation.  The following is an example with $A=\{x,y,z\}$ where $xRx, xRy, yRz, zRy$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way of visualizing this is just by using an example. Lets think of a set

$R = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb N^2 |\text{ such that x and y have the same reminder when devided by 3} \}$

($\mathbb N$ represent all non-negative whole numbers $\pm$0)

So for instance, $(3,9),(8,11)\in R , (4,5)\not \in R$. Or using the more common notation: $3R9, 8R11$ but $4\not R 5$

That is a symmetric binary relation on $\mathbb N$. $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb N$ (they are whole numbers) and $R$ is a sub set of $\mathbb N ^2 $ (R is composed of ordered pairs of whole numbers) .

Answer (score 0):

It might enlighten you to take a look at the Wikipedia article on the theorem on friends and strangers. Here is the link:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers#:~:text=The%20theorem%20says%3A,are%20(pairwise)%20mutual%20acquaintances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_on_friends_and_strangers#:%7E:text=The%20theorem%20says%3A,are%20(pairwise)%20mutual%20acquaintances).
The theorem on friends and strangers can be reformulated abstractly as follows: If A is a set of at least 6 elements and R is a symmetric binary relation on A such that no element of A is related (wrt R) to itself, then there exist either a set of 3 mutually-related (wrt R) elements of A, or a set of 3 mutually-unrelated (wrt R) elements of A.